# Line Wrapping in Collaboratory Google results

Tags: google-colaboratory

Working on Google Collaboratoy (colab) as Notebook, some cell results a long line text which is bigger than the screen resolution, so it is shown a scrollbar with no wrapping.

[image]

Does anyone know how to activate text wrapping to see all text without using scrollbar?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Answer (score 41):

Normally on my own machine, I put this the following css snippit in the `~/.jupyter/custom/custom.css` file.

```css
pre {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

But, the above does not work for google colab: I tried creating a file `/usr/local/share/jupyter/custom/custom.css`, but this didn't work.

### Instead, put this in the first cell of your notebook.

```python
from IPython.display import HTML, display

def set_css():
  display(HTML('''
  <style>
    pre {
        white-space: pre-wrap;
    }
  </style>
  '''))
get_ipython().events.register('pre_run_cell', set_css)
```

Explanation: As described in [Google Colab advanced output](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/snippets/advanced_outputs.ipynb#scrollTo=8dnJ-Z9jTEy9&line=1&uniqifier=1) , `get_ipython().events.register('pre_run_cell', <function name>)`...

> defines an execution hook that loads it [our custom `set_css()` function in our
>   case] automatically each time you execute a cell

My interpretation is that you need to specify `'pre_run_cell'` as the first argument in the `events.register`, which tells the `events.register` function that you wish to run your custom `set_css()` function before the contents of the cell is executed.

This answer was inspired by [How to import CSS file into Google Colab notebook (Python3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58019749/how-to-import-css-file-into-google-colab-notebook-python3/60159121#60159121)

Answer (score 8):

```
from IPython.display import HTML, display

def set_css():
  display(HTML('''
  <style>
    pre {
        white-space: pre-wrap;
    }
  </style>
  '''))
get_ipython().events.register('pre_run_cell', set_css)
```

As Bon Ryu mentioned above, this should solve the issue.
It will wrap your output properly
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I use the following snippet:

```
from IPython.display import HTML, display

def my_css():
   display(HTML("""<style>table.dataframe td{white-space: nowrap;}</style>"""))

get_ipython().events.register('pre_run_cell', my_css)
```

Comment: genius! Now, can we improve it a bit? Some padding on the sides and no splitting of words?

Comment: Doesn't work for me, but https://stackoverflow.com/a/61401455/1535127 does

Answer (score 0):

I create a function to help with that. It works with List and String.

```py
def set_wrap(N=100):
  ''' create a wrap function for list '''
  def wrap(obj):
    s = str(obj)
    out = '<pre>'
    while True:
      if len(s) < N:
        out += s
        break
      i = s.rfind(' ', 0, N)
      if i==-1:
        i = N
      out += s[:i]+"\n"
      s = s[i:]
    out += "</pre>"
    return out
  ''' register it '''
  Formatter = get_ipython().display_formatter.formatters['text/html']
  Formatter.for_type(list, wrap)
  Formatter.for_type(str, wrap)
```

You can use it by just calling `set_wrap(80)`.

Comment: This does not work.