# Can you do a word wrap on an ipython notebook inside Google Colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I would like to word wrap the python code and the output within an python notebook inside Google colab. Is there a way to do that ? Setting vertical alignment within the notebook settings did not resolve this issue for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Line Wrapping in Collaboratory Google results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58890109/line-wrapping-in-collaboratory-google-results)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this in Google Colab with python inbuilt lib 'textwrap'

```
import textwrap

wrapper = textwrap.TextWrapper(width=40,
    initial_indent=" " * 4,
    subsequent_indent=" " * 4,
    break_long_words=False,
    break_on_hyphens=False)

string = "PURPOSE: To end world hunger, create peace for all people, solve all technological and scientific problems, make an exorbitant amount of money, and remain humble in the process."
print wrapper.fill(string)
```

output

```
    PURPOSE: To end world hunger, create peace for all people, solve all
    technological and scientific problems, make an exorbitant amount of money,
    and remain humble in the process.
```