# Problem with viewing string output in Google Colab

Tags: python, string, view, google-colaboratory, abide

[image]

I was supposed to obtain an output like this when i run the command 'print(abide.description)'
But the  output I am obtaining is something like this. The entire string is shown in a single line which is making it quite difficult to read and interpret. How can I obtain the output as the picture above?

My code snippet:

```
print(abide.description)
```

The output:
[image]

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58890109/line-wrapping-in-collaboratory-google-results) answer on formatting output might be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `abide.description` is returning bytes rather than a string. If you want it to print as a normal string, you can use the `bytes.decode()` method to convert the bytes to a unicode string.

For example:

```
content_bytes = b'this is a byte string\nand it will not be wrapped\nunless it is first decoded'

print(content_bytes)
# b'this is a byte string\nand it will not be wrapped\nunless it is first decoded'

print(content_bytes.decode())
# this is a byte string
# and it will not be wrapped
# unless it is first decoded
```