# How to change text color from a python module (tqdm module) output ? (so not python text editor output)

Tags: python, text, colors

I am using the dark theme in Google Colab which automatically transforms text color from output to white.
However, now I am using the progressbar from TQDM module and I get text that is dark colored which is problematic in the dark theme. I was thinking of Colorama but it only changes text color for the text edit (I think?). Here is my code:

```
import yahoo_fin
from yahoo_fin.stock_info import get_data
bar = trange(72)
bar.write("Downloading data...")
for i,stocks in zip(bar,filtered_list):
    df[stocks]= get_data(stocks,stockstart,stockend)['adjclose'].dropna()
bar.write("Completed!")
```

Answer (score 2):

I was having this issue in Colab, and running the following code in a cell solved it for me:

```
# Set the tqdm text color to white.

from IPython.display import HTML, display

def set_css_in_cell_output():
    display(HTML('''
        <style>
            .jupyter-widgets {color: #d5d5d5 !important;}
            .widget-label {color: #d5d5d5 !important;}
        </style>
    '''))

get_ipython().events.register('pre_run_cell', set_css_in_cell_output)
```

(Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60159121/1658458) StackOverflow answer)

Answer (score 0):

using tqdm.bar_format it works:

```
# first arg is for percentage
# 2nd one is for the bar
# 3rd one is for the end of the line 
read_bar_format = "%s{l_bar}%s{bar}%s{r_bar}" % (
        "\033[0;32m", "\033[0;32m", "\033[0;32m"
    )

for x in tqdm(range(100), bar_format=read_bar_format):#colour='green'):
    time.sleep(.1)
```

Answer (score -3):

tqdm==4.64.1

The tqdm function has an argument colour

```
tqdm(m_db,colour='green')
```

complete code

```
for i in tqdm(range(5), colour="green"):
     print(i)
```

Comment: Setting `colour` changes only the colour of the progress bar, but not the font colour.