# make tqdm bar dark in VSCode Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I am using Jupyter notebooks in Visual Studio Code with dark mode enabled. I visualize progress bars with tqdm, but it does not show up dark. See the image:
[image]

According to [this issue](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/issues/842#issuecomment-553870106) on GitHub, this is not a problem with the Jupyter, ipywidget or tqdm itself, and it is related only to **VSCode**.

Is there any workaround to fix this?

Comment: The workaround which is a bit hacky consists of doing both of these things:
(1) Setting the default pywidgets background color to black in vscode: See [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73826994/5659969)
and (2) Setting the widgets style for text color as an IPython pre cell run event (to get white text): See [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67745989/5659969)

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/7161#issuecomment-1616627670) worked for me. Run the code below in a cell.

```css
%%html
<style>
.cell-output-ipywidget-background {
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
:root {
    --jp-widgets-color: var(--vscode-editor-foreground);
    --jp-widgets-font-size: var(--vscode-editor-font-size);
}  
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the [tqdm-bar_format](https://tqdm.github.io/docs/tqdm/) argument to tqdm with a custom format that uses ANSI escape codes to set the color.

something like this:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
import time

# Custom format with ANSI escape codes for dark green color
dark_green = "\033[1;32;40m"
bar_format = f"{dark_green}{{l_bar}}{{bar:50}} [{{elapsed}}]{{r_bar}}"

# Create tqdm progress bar with custom format
for i in tqdm(range(100), bar_format=bar_format):
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

Also, [This-Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842424/list-of-ansi-color-escape-sequences) can be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and [my search](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/9403#issuecomment-1072547892) revealed that entering the following alone in a cell cured the background display issue but the text being dark could be a problem still on dark background. I set mine to a peach color page as a compromise (see screenshot):

```
%%html
<style>
.cell-output-ipywidget-background {
   background-color: transparent !important;
}
.jp-OutputArea-output {
   background-color: transparent;
}  
</style>
```

[image]